# Fullpage scroll for Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there an analogue library [fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for Vue? Need a component that can scroll through components as well as for [fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can also make use of [the official fullpage.js component for Vue.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/vue-fullpage/)

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Sorry, what about pure js library? I don't want to use jQuery in my app, but vue-fullpage have dependencies of fullpage.js and that have dependecies of jQuery. Thx

Comment: The pure-javascript version is very out of date. It has been years since the last update on it and it contains multiple bugs as well as a much reduced functionality. 

You'll have to wait for the next big update of fullPage.js, which will for sure get rid of jQuery and probably drop compatibility with IE 8 and 9.

Comment: Thx for answer, Alvaro.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can consider a `directive` for that.

First load `jquery` and `fullpage`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
```

Then create a new directive.

```
Vue.directive('fullpage', function(el, binding) {
  $(el).fullpage(binding.value)
})
```

Example usage:

```
<div v-fullpage="fullpageOptions">
  ...
</div>
```

In your component:

```
data: {
  return {
    fullpageOptions: {
      sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
      anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
      menu: '#menu',
      css3: true,
      scrollingSpeed: 1000
    }
  }
}
```